# How to delete a table row on button click of corresponding row?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
    function deleteHostTable(src) {
        var table = src.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        if(table.rows.length > 1) {             
            table.deleteRow(src.parentNode.parentNode);
        }
         }
    function addHost(src) {
         var table = src.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length-1);

        var cell = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);

        cell.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name = "vtierIdH" value = "vtierId" />'

        cell = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
        cell.innerHTML = '<img src="images/minus.gif" onclick="deleteHostTable(this);return false;"/>';

        cell = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
        cell.className = "pagetitle";
        cell.innerHTML = '<input type = "text" value="hstst" />';
    }
</script>
<html>
<table id="host#1" index="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">
            <h2 align="left" class="pagetitle">Sub Account Hosts:</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="vtierIdH" value="<%=vtierId %>" />

            <td><button id="minus" onclick="deleteHostTable(this);"/></td>
            <td class="pagetitle"><input type="text" value="hstst" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button  onclick="addHost(this);"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Now, when i click the button corresponding to a button, this code deletes the uppermost row
and not the row corresponding to that button which is clicked. How can i delete the row corresponding to the button in that row?

Comment: It is not doing anything . It is not even deleting the upper most row.

Comment: @all ThankYou so much your answers are really elegant.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answers as accepted/useful. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your remove function to

```
function deleteHostTable(src) {
    var row = src.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

The reason it's not working with `deleteRow` is that it expects the index of the row to be passed while you are passing an object.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass "index" to the table.deleteRow function, not the element.

```
function deleteHostTable(src) {

    var table = src.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var row = src.parentNode.parentNode;
    for(var i = table.rows.length; i--; )
    {
        if ( table.rows[i] == row )
        {
            table.deleteRow(i);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

this function should work.

You also can use src.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(src.parentNode.parentNode)